# Define and use a Text column as id in persistent mongodb

Tags: haskell, persistent

I'm trying to define and use a table (AKA collection) with a Text column as the unique id. I'm using the 2.0.2 versions of persistent, persistent-mongodb, persistent-template.

This is my table definition:

```
let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoContext)) { mpsGeneric = False }
  in  share [mkPersist mongoSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"][persistUpperCase|
User id=myid
  myid     Text
  count    Int
|]
```

I can't figure out how to create a `Key User` from a `Text` value.
I attempted:

```
mkUser :: Text -> Key User
mkUser x = UserKey . MongoKey $ x
```

with compiler error:

> ```
> Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘ObjectId’
> Expected type: Text -> Key User
>   Actual type: ObjectId -> Key User
> ```

Are mongo keys in persistent only allowed to be of type `ObjectId`? From my examination of the relevant [source code](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/75bc568fdb341345be6eb4c5e46e69a8de417dc8/persistent-mongoDB/Database/Persist/MongoDB.hs#L487), this seems to be the case, but I would love to be wrong.  Mongodb certainly allows textual keys outside of persistent. In fact, it allows for [any unique thing](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/).

I also tried inserting a row like so:

```
insert $ User "bob" 0
```

but the resulting database row has an auto-generated `ObjectId` in the `_id` column, instead of `"bob"`.

If I define the schema:

```
User sql=profiles
  _id    Text
  count  Int
```

then I still have the issue of attempting to define a `Key User` with a `Text` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature in persistent-mongoDB (that was not available when I asked the question), so the answer used to be "No, that's not possible" but is now "Yes, and here is how". It's available as of the 2.0.3 series: persistent-2.0.3, persistent-template-2.0.3, and persistent-mongoDB-2.0.3.

Your schema should have a line: `Id <type of _id field>` For example:

```
let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoContext)) { mpsGeneric = False }
  in  share [mkPersist mongoSettings][persistUpperCase|
User
  Id   Text
  age  Int
|]
```

and you insert documents with a specific `_id` like this:

```
insertKey (UserKey "alice") $ User 1
```

Also see the [wiki](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#change-tablecollection-id-field-name-andor-type-persistent--21).